# JS-Counter: Set up different speeds (Interval) in one function

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter, flip

I have this following Code:

```js
var count=0;

var counter=setInterval(timer, 50); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
  count=count+1;
  if (count >= 24)
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     //counter ended, do something here
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML=24 ;
      
     return;
  }

  //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
     document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML=count ; // watch for spelling

}
```

```css
#countdown{
    font-size: 5em ;
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown">0</div>
```

I'd like to set up the counter, so it runs in different speeds.

```
From count 0 to 10 - speed = 50
From count 11 to 20 - speed = 500
From count 21 to 50 - speed = 5000
```

I'd tried to add the line

```
if (count == 11)
{var counter=setInterval(timer, 500); }
```

but this didn't work.

How can I realize to setup three different speeds in one function?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just rewrote everything. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
value: 1000, inc: 123, pace: 1000, auto: true
```

the pace is set to 1000 milliseconds mate!

Just change that number and you will have any speed you want!

Comment: But i need a Flip counter with several Speeds in one Script. In the beginning and end it shall count slow, in the middle part really fast...

Comment: why don't you just start it up three times, each time remember the previous value `value: previousValue`